# Can we find a tidy formula for a generalization of the self-generating sequence A007538, featured in A-6 of the 1993 Putnam exam?

Tags: recurrence-relations, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, closed-form, continued-fractions

## Main Question

### Setup

Given nonnegative integer parameters $x$ and $y$, we define a sequence $\langle a_n:n=0,1,\ldots \rangle$ which alternates between a single $x$ and runs of consecutive entries equal to $y$, where the length of each run is given by the corresponding entry in the sequence.

For example, if $x=2$ and $y=3$, we have the sequence: $2,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,\ldots$ where the first runs of $3$s have lengths $2,3,3,2$, respectively, because those are the first entries in the sequence. If $x=3$ and $y=0$, we have a sequence: $3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3,\ldots$

### Question

The cases of $x=0$ or $x=y$ both lead to $a_n=x$ for all $n$. Less trivially, in the special case where $y=x+1$, $a_n$ is given by a tidy non-recursive formula involving [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and a square root, such as $a_n=\left\lfloor(n+1)\cdot\dfrac{x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor (n)\cdot\dfrac{x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}\right\rfloor-1\tag{1}\text{.}$

**Is there a similar closed form for the general case?**

## Context

I discovered this collection of sequences in [What is the pattern in this infinite sequence? [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3905658/26369), where [BOBOBOY](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/849026/boboboy) was asking for Python code to generate the sequences. I tried briefly to find a tidy formula on my own, and noted that the indices where $a_i=x$ are $0,1+a_0,2+a_0+a_1,3+a_0+a_1+a_2,\ldots$.

This means we could define the sequence by $$a_{n}=\begin{cases}
x & \text{if }n=0\\
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if }k=n\\
y & \text{if }k>n
\end{cases}\text{ where }k\text{ is least so }k+1+\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_{i}\ge n & \text{if }n>0
\end{cases}\tag{2}\text{.}$$

It turns out that the case $x=2$ and $y=3$ is [A007538](http://oeis.org/A007538) in the OEIS because the question of identifying the indices where $a_n=2$ (essentially the same as finding a formula for $a_n$) was question A-6 on the 1993 [Putnam Exam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Lowell_Putnam_Mathematical_Competition). You can see one phrasing of the question and a solution at Kalva ([questions](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/putn93.html), [solution](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol936.html)) and another at [the MAA article for that Putnam](https://doi.org/10.2307/2974527).

The solution to that Putnam problem readily generalizes from $x=2,y=3$ to all $y=x+1$ (though $x=0$ may need to be checked separately): the indices where $a_n=x$ are those of the form $\left\lfloor (m)\cdot\dfrac{x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}\right\rfloor$, which leads quickly to the formula (1) above. (The formula simplifies a bit if $x$ is known to be even or known to be odd.)

It seems a new approach/sort of formula is needed for the general case, but I'm not sure what form to guess. I doubt there is a very similar formula with a different (usually) irrational number depending on both $x$ and $y$, because the asymptotic heuristics featured in the MAA article seem to lead one to the guess of $\dfrac{y+1+\sqrt{(y-1)^2+4x}}{2}$, which doesn't seem to work unless $y=x+1$.

(I'm open to other tags, but chose [continued-fractions](/questions/tagged/continued-fractions) simply because they came up in the comments of the related [A188070](http://oeis.org/A188070), and quadratic irrationals have periodic continued fractions.)